# Pre-1995 movie where a group enter a portal in a cave to another world

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie in the late '90s as a kid. A group of people explore a cave and find a portal to another world. It was a murky portal, either on the side of the cave or the ground. There are all sorts of monsters in this new world, and there was a conveyor belt machine which would turn humans into a large pitch black monster.

Unfortunately I don't remember much more as I was too frightened as a kid and didn't finish the movie.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was the movie live-action or animated?  What language?

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps [Equinox](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0067055/), a “cult classic” movie where a group of young adults explore a cave which leads to another world filled with monsters. Later, there is a murky portal which further leads to source world. A human (the ranger) turns into a monster.

The only common element I don’t recall is any conveyor belt, although prolific fantasy author Fritz Lieber starred in the film as a scientist, and I recall credits including gears or machines so there may be technological elements in the film as well.

Released in 1970, it is a pre-1995 movie which could be watched in the late 90s.

Comment: I suspected you might have confused acting roles of Fritz Lieber Sr. (1882-1949) & Jr. (1910-92), as many have, but it was indeed writer Fritz Lieber Jr. in the film Equinox (1970).  But whenever Fritz Lieber is in film credits, check to see which one it is.